# UberAll API "Cannot parse the opening hours"

Tags: api, postman

Trying to employ the UberAll API, and getting back an error message that I can't explain or get around.  (I'm doing this right now in Postman--eventually to port into an SSIS C# script--part of which is already done and works.)

I am trying to update a Location with the following (json) payload:

```
{
    "paymentOptions":"AMEX,APPLEPAY,CASH,CASH ONLY,CHECK,DEBIT,MASTERCARD,VISA",
    "email":"Customer.Care@stuffstuffstuff.com",
    "website":"http://www.stuffstuffstuff.com",
    "keywords":"coffee,gas station food,Fuel,Gas Station",
    "openingHours":"Mo=05:30-22:30; Tu=05:30-22:30; We=05:30-22:30; Th=05:30-22:30; Fr=05:30-22:30; Sa=05:30-22:30; Su=06:00-22:30",
    "descriptionShort":"etc etc etc etc etc etc etc"
}
```

...and I get back the following message:

```
{
    "status": "INVALID_PARAMETER",
    "message": "Cannot parse the opening hours",
    "response": {
        "openingHours": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
    }
}
```

Accoring to the UberAll API documentation:

```
Example:
Mo=08:00-16:00;Di=08:00-15:00&17:00-19:00;Mi=08:00-16:00;Do=08:00-16:00;Fr=08:00-16:00;Sa;So
```

(Obviously, the days there are abbreviated in German.)

I've tried with and without the spaces.

I can't tell what else might be wrong with what I've formatted--or, what am I missing?

Comment: I tried playing around some more.
If I remove that line, the rest works.
If I remove everything else and just have that line, the result is the same.